# Decision Table with a condition on a set containing values coming from lists

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, business-rules

Using Drools 6.0.1 I would like to set a **CONDITION** (on a column of a Decision Table) similar to the following one:

```
ProductDrools(productCategories contains $param)
```

(that then would go in every rule after a `when` in a `drl` file) where `productCategories` is a `Set` (e.g. an `HashSet`) that, for now, I am only able to check against one string per cell e.g. `"categoryA"`.

I would like to provide in the spreadsheet cell a `List`, array, `Set` (any `Collection`) of multiple strings representing categories e.g. `"categoryA", "catB", "catX"`. 
The [official documentation for Drools 6.0.1](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html/) does not provide enough information regarding operators like `contains`.

Is this scenario achievable? How? Is there any documentation regarding this you could point me to?

Comment: There is no operator for testing for an non-empty intersection of two sets. You could create a custom operator, based on the code of "in".

Comment: Oh good to know, thanks. Do you know where to find the source code of that operator? I am kind of lost in all the projects in their Git repositories.

Comment: When you download, you also get some jars containing the sources. See ./org/drools/core/base/evaluators/SetEvaluatorsDefinition.java. Also, you might google "Drools operator definition", although that code was developed for 5.3.